# Is there any way to optimize next query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I need to calculate statistic for table. I wrote next SQL:

```
     SELECT
          DISTINCT ("region"),
          COUNT(*) as total,
          COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE t1.insert_status = 'success' AND t1.insert_status = 'success') as completed,
          COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE t1.insert_status IS NULL AND t1.insert_status IS NULL ) as waiting,
          COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE t1.insert_status = 'failed' ) as insert_failed
          FROM xml_files t1

        WHERE t1.section_name='payments'
        AND processed_date >='2010-07-28' AND processed_date <='2021-08-28'
        
        group by region
```

The problem that my table is too big (50 millions rows) and it took too much time to get result. Is there any way to optimize this query?

What ways of optimizations are possible?

Comment: Your query is missing a `WHERE` clause.  And `t1` is not defined.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b` - and combination with `group by` this makes even less sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you almost never need `select distinct` with `group by`.  Second, your query has syntax errors.

Assuming you intend:

```
SELECT region,
       COUNT(*) as total,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE t1.insert_status = 'success' AND t1.insert_status = 'success') as completed,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE t1.insert_status IS NULL AND t1.insert_status IS NULL ) as waiting,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE t1.insert_status = 'failed' ) as insert_failed
FROM xml_files t1
WHERE t1.section_name = 'payments' AND
      t1.processed_date >='2010-07-28' AND t1.processed_date <='2021-08-28'        
GROUP BY region;
```

Then you want an index on `xml_files(second_name, processed_date, region, insert_status)`.

Comment: Does composite index give significant benefit in performance?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Does it make any sense `t1.insert_status = 'success' AND t1.insert_status = 'success'`? The same in the next line. Could you please give an example (or a link) where `distinct` and `group by` on the same column(s) are both required?

Comment: @Steeeve . . . I didn't write the query.  I tried to fix it up as reasonably as possible.  You should address the question to the OP.

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov . . . A composite index can be a big win, especially if the database is able to do an index-only scan.

Comment: @GordonLinoff big thanks. I tested composite index and get speed increase in 2 times.

Comment: Hi. Maybe in your case partitioning by date could be a big improvement, if you don't need all the time 11 years being processed by your query.

Comment: Anyway, I'm curious, can this query be faster than the one based on count(*) and Filter... could you test it .. `SELECT region,
SUM (1) as total
SUM ( 1 * CASE t1.insert_status = 'success' WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as completed,
SUM ( 1 * CASE t1.insert_status IS NULL  WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as waiting,
SUM ( 1 * CASE t1.insert_status = 'failed'  WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as insert_failed,
FROM xml_files t1
WHERE t1.section_name = 'payments' AND
t1.processed_date >='2010-07-28' AND t1.processed_date <='2021-08-28'        
GROUP BY region; `

Comment: @MiguelSuazo . . . I don't know.  You can ask a new question.